# Escaping square brackets in regex

Tags: regex

I have these words:
`FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS = {"single", "[several] words"}`

I need a regex that simultaneously:

(a) extract a single whole word (e.g. "single" **SHOULD** be matched)
(b) ignore parts of that single whole word (e.g. "sing" should **NOT** be matched, since it's a part of the "single" word)
(b) extract several words expression (e.g. "[several] words" **SHOULD** be matched)
(c) ignore these words from words expression if they are not part of this expression (e.g "several" should **NOT** be matched, because it's not part of "several words" in this case)

In other words, my pytest should pass:

```
FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS = {"single", "several words"}

(a) ("Single word example", 'Single'),
(b) ("I like to sing", None),
(c) ("[Several] words example", '[Several] words'),
(d) ("[Several] apples", None),
```

My code:

`re.compile( r"\b(" + "|".join(FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS) + r")\b", re.IGNORECASE )`

It works only for (a) AND (b) cases now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some examples of input and expected output for it.

Comment: @makalex. Added tests, any ideas?

Comment: You could use group `(Several) words` to extract only `Several` from `Several words`

Comment: In general, everything seems fine. It's unclear to me why in your third example only the word 'Several' is expected, but if it's your conscious decision, you should use the filter `several(?= words)` instead.

Comment: Now it's even less clear. Why are you expecting 'example' to be matched if your filter contains only 'several words', and why don't you expect 'Single word' to be matched in the first test?

Comment: Your last sentence is throwing me off a bit here. The regex you came up with [works](https://regex101.com/r/1puB0l/1) for all cases stated when I try it. Do you have a problem with looping over your samples perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, @JvdV. With your help I've realized that some of the items in long FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS is surrounded by square brackets.

Comment: '[]' in regex have special meaning. You should escape them before using in regex. Like so: `\[several\]`

Comment: Or rather, update the body of the question to reflect what problem you *actually* have that  you need help with.

Comment: Also you'll most likely will need to drop `\b`, because `\[several` doesn't match `abc [several`: change between space and the square bracket doesn't count as a word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape regex's special symbols before using them as part of the expression.

Also if non word symbols expected to be first symbol in filter item, it's better to remove `\b`, as it will prevent matching strings like `do [smth]` with pattern `\b\[smth` because transition from space to square bracket is not a word boundary.

Here is example how it could be done:

```py
import re

FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS = {"single", "[seve.ral] words"}

tests = ["Single word example",
         "I like to sing",
         "[Seve.ral] words example",
         "[Seve.ral] apples", ]

rc = re.compile(
    r"(" + "|".join([re.sub(r'([][(){}.|+*?^$\\])', r'\\\1', ftoken) for ftoken in FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS]) + r")",
    re.IGNORECASE)

for test in tests:
    print(test, rc.findall(test))
```

And here is its output:

```
Single word example ['Single']
I like to sing []
Several words example ['Several words']
Several apples []
```

Comment: Thank you, @markalex. I've realized that some of the items in long FALSE_POSITIVE_TEXT_TERMS is surrounded by square brackets

Comment: @arthur, replaced answer for your new question.